# Fail to sort 3 different list using sorting library ng2-dnd

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, angular

Im  using some nice and [simple drag-and-drop library from github](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd), and I have a view with 3 different buttons each presenting a list when its being clicked in the same place but NOT on the same time.

From some reason only the first list can be sorted but the other 2 re not...I can move the objects but they are not droppable so I cant change the order.

this is my html:

```
<div>
  <!-- list 1 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showFirstList()"
          class="md-primary">List 1
  </button>

  <!-- list 2 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showSecondList()"
          class="md-primary">List 2

  </button>

  <!-- list 3 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="ThirdList()"
          class="md-primary">List 3

  </button>
</div>


        <md-content>

          <div *ngIf="showingListOne">
            <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOneToDisplay | async">
              <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listOneToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> name: {{item.name}}
              </div>
            </div><br><br>
          </div>


          <div *ngIf="showingListTwo">
            <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-two']" [sortableData]="listTwoToDisplay | async">
              <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listTwoToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div *ngIf="showingListThree">
            <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-three']"  [sortableData]="listThreeToDisplay | async">
              <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listThreeToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
          </div>

        </md-content>
```

this is my sorting-lists.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sorting-lists',
  styles: [require('./sorting-lists.css')],
  directives: [DND_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [DND_PROVIDERS],
  template: require('./sorting-lists.component.html')
})

@Injectable()
export class MyCmp implements OnInit {

  listOneToDisplay  = this._myService.getFirstListData();
  listTwoToDisplay = this._myService.getSecondListData();
  listThreeToDisplay = this._myService.getThirdListData();

  showingListOne = false;
  showingListTwo = false;
  showingListThree = false;

  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
  };


  public showFirstList(): void {
    this.showingListOne = true;
    this.showingListTwo = false;
    this.showingListThree = false;
  }

  public showSecondList(): void {
    this.showingListTwo = true;
    this.showingListOne = false;
    this.showingListThree = false;
  }

  public showThirdList(): void {
    this.showingListThree = true;
    this.showingListTwo = false;
    this.showingListOne = false;
  }

}
```

if someone can help me figure out why only the first one is sortable it will be blessed!!

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should avoid use the "async" filter - look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ZZsz4?p=preview)

```
export class AppComponent {
listDrinks:Array<string>=[];
listFamousPeople:Array<string> = [];
listMotorsysces:Array<string> = [];




constructor(_myService:myService) {
   _myService.getDrinks().subscribe(drink => this.listDrinks = drink)
   _myService.getPeople().subscribe(p =>  this.listFamousPeople = p);
   _myService.getBikes().subscribe(m => this.listMotorsysces =m);
}
```

and in template:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Favorite drinks
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group" dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="listDrinks">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of listDrinks; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Famous People
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group" dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="listFamousPeople">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of listFamousPeople; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Favorite Motorsysces
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group" dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="listMotorsysces">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of listMotorsysces; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```